# Do Keras Layers input and output tensors, or other Layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The [tf.Keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) states:

> A layer is a callable object that takes as input one or more tensors and that outputs one or more tensors.

But then the whole [Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) seems to be based calling a Layer object with another Layer as an input.

Do layers take in tensors and output tensors, or do they take in layers and output something else?

Comment: No, when you use the Functional API, each call through a layer produces a tensor, not another layer, just look at the types of the objects produced.

Comment: I was confusing `Input` with `InputLayer` -- thanks.